# Login loop in Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox with real HDD

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, virtualbox, login

I want to use the same Ubuntu instance by two ways: as a full functional system on real hardware and in VirtualBox on my Windows 8.1 system.

The Ubuntu is installed to a separate hard drive.

I used this instruction to get access to physical hard drive.
https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box

Ubuntu boots from both real computer and from VirtualBox, but I have problem with usage them together.

My computer has geForce 1050Ti graphics card which is not supported in 16.04 by default.
If I do not install NVidia drivers, the system loads perfectly in VirtualBox, but cannot be booted on real computer and hangs. I can boot it only with nouveau.modeset=0 grub option, but it works terrible with it (works very laggy and supports only 1 display)

If I install **any** version of Nvidia drivers (from 375 to 390), the system works perfectly on real computer, but goes into login loop in VirtualBox.

What I tried to solve the problem:

1) remove or change permissions for .Xauthority

2) reinstall xorg and ubuntu-desktop

3) install different versions of Nvidia drivers: from 375 to the latest 390

4) restart and reconfigure lightdm

5) install or do not install VirtualBox guest additions

6) tried to use these commands

```
sudo apt install mokutil
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

I tried all of these options together or separately on fresh installed system. Nothing helps.

Also I tried Ubuntu 17.10, it works perfectly and can be booted on real hardware and in VirtualBox without any issues. But unfrotunately I need exactly 16.04 for my purposes.

Maybe is there any option to disable Nvidia drivers at boot?

Comment: One way: Use a different kernel for each "machine" (one with NVIDIA, one without) and use GRUB to select between the kernels at boot-time. It's not-trivial to maintain.

Comment: how to do this? is there any instruction or example?

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that you want the maintenance headache? People don't do this for a reason. I'm not aware if any "instructions": One kernel (like the current one) for Vbox, and another kernel (like the previous) with your hardware drivers. You, the human, must keep track of the differences and choose the correct kernel at boot. You must also disable automatic kernel updates (which will erase your kernel work), so must keep track of new kernel versions and upgrade kernels manually. If you don't understand what I just wrote, then DON'T DO IT.

Comment: I want to try this an option:) Anyway there is nothing to loose for me:)